# Python shape detector code

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am writing an object oriented shape detector, first time in Python. I come from a Java background. Can you provide any coding advice?

https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/02/08/opencv-shape-detection/

```
@dataclass
class Coordinate:
    x_value: int
    y_value: int


@dataclass
class Rectangle:
    coordinate_upper_left: Coordinate
    width: float
    height: float


from cv2 import cv2
from numpy.random import randint

import constants.shape_constants as shape_constants
from models.coordinate import Coordinate
from models.rectangle import Rectangle

class ShapeItem():

    def __init__(self, curve_data):
        # these items must run in sequence to be set correctly
        self.curve_data = curve_data
        self.drawing_item_id = uuid.uuid4()
        self.approx_poly_dp = self.get_approx_poly()
        self.vertices = self.get_vertices()
        self.bounded_rectangle = self.get_bounded_rectangle()
        self.center_coordinate = self.get_center_coordinate()
        self.shape = self.get_shape()

    def get_approx_poly(self):
        perimeter_value = cv2.arcLength(self.curve_data, True)
        return cv2.approxPolyDP(self.curve_data, 0.04 * perimeter_value, True)

    def get_vertices(self):
        vertices_list : list[Coordinate] = []
        vertices_data_curve = self.approx_poly_dp.tolist()
        for vertices_in_shape in [vertices_data_curve]:
            for vertices_shape_two_brackets in vertices_in_shape:
                for vertices_shape_one_bracket in vertices_shape_two_brackets:
                    vertices_item = Coordinate(vertices_shape_one_bracket[0], vertices_shape_one_bracket[1])
                    vertices_list.append(vertices_item)

        return vertices_list

    def get_bounded_rectangle(self):
        (x_cv, y_cv, width_cv, height_cv) = cv2.boundingRect(self.approx_poly_dp)
        bounded_rectangle = Rectangle(
            coordinate_upper_left=Coordinate(x_cv, y_cv),
            width=width_cv,
            height=height_cv
        )
        return bounded_rectangle

    def get_shape(self):
        shape_value: str
        if len(self.vertices) == 3:
            shape_value = shape_constants.TRIANGLE
        elif len(self.vertices) == 4:
            shape_value = shape_constants.RECTANGLE
        elif len(self.vertices) == 5:
            shape_value = shape_constants.PENTAGON
        else:
            shape_value = shape_constants.ELLIPSE
        return shape_value

    def get_secondary_shape(self):
        if self.shape == shape_constants.RECTANGLE and \
            0.95 <= (self.bounded_rectangle.width / float(self.bounded_rectangle.height) <= 1.05):
            return shape_constants.SQUARE
        else:
            return shape_constants.RECTANGLE

    def get_center_coordinate(self):
        moment_data = cv2.moments(self.curve_data)
        center_x = int((moment_data["m10"] / moment_data["m00"]))
        center_y = int((moment_data["m01"] / moment_data["m00"]))
        center_coordinate = Coordinate(center_x, center_y)
        return center_coordinate

    def set_background_color(self):
        random_color_index = randint(1, 10)
        return random_color_index
```

Comment: Could you include your imports as well? Where is `DrawingItem` defined? What is `cv2`?

Comment: just added @Linny